# fatal: packfile name 'server' does not end with '.pack'

Tags: git

I had a non-bare git repository.  I wanted to create a bare repository in a server to which I have an SSH access and make it the origin of the older repository.

I first created a bare repository in a directory `X` in an NFS partition by `git init --bare`.
Then I signified in the original repository the origin as `git remote add origin myusername@myserver:X`.  (In fact, I tried with the wrong user name and tried to push it for a couple of times; I deleted the wrong specification by `git remote rm origin`.)

When I tried to push, I got an error:

```
 fatal: packfile name 'myserver' does not end with '.pack'
```

Why am I failing in pushing?  What is a possible workaround?

Addendum:  `X` is in full path.

Comment: Do you see X if you do a `ssh myusername@myserver ls`?

Comment: @VonC I do. (Thank you for your attention)

Comment: And do you see the usual bare repo content in X? `branches/`, `config`, `info/`, `logs/`, `refs/`, ...

Comment: Just in case that has any effect, could you try and do a `git init --bare X.Git`, and change the remote to point to that new bare repo `X.git` (`git remote set-url origin myusername@myserver:X.git`)

Comment: @VonC Do you mean that the name of the repository matters?  My `X` already ends in `.git`.

Comment: Ok, I thought it didn't use the `.git` extension yet. Can you clone that existing bare git repo?

Comment: @VonC Yes, I can, but I get an empty directory with a message `warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.`

Comment: That is expected. From that clone, can you just make a commit (create a new file, add and commit), for test, and push it back?

Comment: @VonC I can do that.  Besides, if you clone the repo somewhere else, you can see the content just added.

Comment: So the issue might not be from the remote bare git repo, but from the existing content of the local repo you are trying to push...

Comment: Running on the idea of a corrupt local repository, maybe try running `git fsck` to see if the local repository has missing or corrupt data?

Comment: @Hargobind Thank you for your suggestion; however, `git fsck` finishes w/o errors.